# Sendmail Postfix long delays

Tags: smtp, sendmail, postfix-mta, centos6.5

I am using PHP's mail function to send messages to the users of an application.
But I have been getting reports that some people don't receive them, and that others have arrived up to a couple of hours later.

So I was looking through /var/log/maillog, where I came across this message a lot:

```
postfix/smtp[22966]: connect to mx1.hotmail.com[65.55.37.104]:25: Connection timed out.
```

There were a lot of delays over 1000 sec in the log.

I have checked the firewall settings, and there are no rules stopping port 25, and this problem is not consistent, some emails go out fine, while others are sent with a long delay, and others are not sent at all.

Any suggestions for what to try next?

Running on CentOS 6.5.

Answer (score 0):

From what you describe, it sounds like some of the remote mail servers that you are sending to could be [greylisting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greylisting) your mail server, perhaps because it thinks that your mail server could be a spammer.

To see if your mail server has a glaring problem that would cause other mail servers to think it's a spammer, try sending a message from your mail server to `check-auth@verifier.port25.com`. This service will do a bunch of checks, and you'll get a report back with ton of information, such whether or not your mail server's DNS is setup correctly, whether your mail server's IP is on any black lists, if you have a problem with your SPF records, etc.